# String altering in Ant

Tags: java, ant

Given a property:

```
<property name="classes" value="com.package.Class1,com.package.Class2" />
```

I'm trying to compile only the classes specified like:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
    <include name="${classes}" />
</javac>
```

However the 'include' tag is specifying the file names to include, not the qualified class names.

Is there a way I can create a new property/include tag that has all the classes in 'classes' in the correct format? ie.

```
"com.package.Class1" -> "com\\package\\Class1.java"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  After ant-contrib I can do one of these:

```
<propertyregex property="classes.resolved"
        input="${classes}"
        regexp="\."
        replace="\\\\" />
```